# Why is my form submitting too early?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form on one page, and the submit button on that page leads the user to the next page of the form.  I'm trying to set it up so that the info from form 1 is submitted along with form 2's info when the submit button on form 2 is clicked and all forms have been filled out, however, the first form's data is being submitted to my database when proceeding to form 2.  Any ideas why this is the case?  And any ideas of a solution?

Also, I am getting an error "undefined index GET" from the first form and I am struggling to understand why?

Thanks in advance!

**Form 1 (parent.php)**

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['fName']=$GET['fName'];
$_SESSION['sName']=$GET['sName'];
$_SESSION['email']=$GET['email'];
$_SESSION['address']=$GET['address'];


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”     “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=iso-8859-1″ />
<title>table2</title>
</head>
<h1>Is this in xamppfiles and htdocs?</h1>




<form action="child2.php" method="post" class="validate">
<div>
<input class="tb" type="text" name="fName" placeholder="first name" id="fName" value=" <?php $fName ?>" required/><br/>
 <br/>
  <input class="tb" type="text" name="sName" placeholder="surname" id="sName" value="<?php $sName ?>" required/><br/>
  <br/>
  <input class="tb" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="email address" id="email" value="<?php $email ?>" required/>
  <br/>
  <input class="tb" type="address" name="address" placeholder="address" value="<?php $address ?>" id="address" />
  <br/>


  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
  </div>
  </form> 




</body>
</html>
```

**Form 2 (child2.php)**

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  include("connect.php");
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”   “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=iso-8859-1″ />

<title>table2</title>
</head>

<body>


 <?php
function renderForm($fName, $sName, $email, $address){ 
?>



<form action="" method="post" class="validate">

<label class="label">first name</label><input class="tb" type="text" id="fName"     name="fName" value="<?php if (isset($fName)) { echo $fName = $_SESSION['fName'];} else {    if(!isset($fName)) { echo ""; }}?>"/> 
</br>
<label class="label">surname</label><input class="tb" type="text" id="sName"  name="sName" value="<?php if (isset($sName)) { echo $sName = $_SESSION['sName'];} else {  if(!isset($sName)) { echo ""; }}?>"/>
</br>
<label class="label">email</label><input class="tb" type="email" id="email"  name="email" value="<?php if (isset($email)) { echo $email = $_SESSION['email'];} else { if(!isset($email)) { echo ""; }}?>""/>
</br>
<label class="label">address</label><input class="tb" type="text" id="address"  name="address" value="<?php if (isset($address)) { echo $address = $_SESSION['address'];}    else { if(!isset($address)) { echo ""; }}?>""/>
</br>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php
}


// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $fName = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fName']));
 $sName = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sName']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
 $address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));

 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($fName == '' || $sName == '' || $email == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($fName, $sName, $email, $address, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT formtest SET fName='$fName', sName='$sName',email='$email', address='$address'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: child2.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','','','');
 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do mean `$_SESSION['fName']=$_GET['fName']; ` ?

Comment: Both forms submit to `child2.php`, and `isset($_POST['submit'])` will be true when you submit either form. That's why it's saving to the DB when submitting the first form.

Comment: `<?php $variable ?>` won't do anything, by the way. Did you mean `<?= $variable ?>` or `<?php echo $variable; ?>`?

Comment: Ah, thank you with the $_GET, I'm an idiot!  Although, I am now getting 'Undefined index' for the 'sName' 'fName' etc that come after $_GET?

Comment: @minitech, thanks, I've just realised I don't even need that in there.

Comment: @bfavaretto , thanks for your help.  How should I resolve this, should I set it up so it's ifisset 'otherbutton' AND 'submit' in the 2nd form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action field of your parent.php is child2.php . Also, you are checking for

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

which is set true by your first page, hence, it goes inside the loop and inserts the data in your database. This can be resolved by placing this in your parent file

```
  <input id="submit" name="submitINIT" type="submit" value="Next">
```

A possible solution can be, you extract the values of the first form and store it in some session variables , and finally at final submission, you can use those values for insertion.

In your child2.php, do this

```
 if (isset($_POST['submitINIT'])){
   // store all the available values in some session variables
$_SESSION['value1']=$POST['fName'];
$_SESSION['value2']=$POST['sName'];
$_SESSION['value3']=$POST['email'];
$_SESSION['value4']=$POST['address'];
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   // proceed after final submission
}
```

Also, change the action of 2nd file to itself using this

```
<form action="child2.php" method="post" class="validate">
```

Also, do this modification in your child2.php

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Prashant, thanks, I've changed the first submit button to as you suggested but then I no longer get the values that are stored from the textboxes into the session to display on the 2nd form?

Comment: @rosewit Accept it as answer, if, it serves your part or ask if u get some other problem